# How to show form required warning in collapsed details?

Tags: html, forms, html-tag-details

I have a form with a required checkbox inside a details tag.
When the user tries to submit the site without checking the checkbox a warning is displayed.

But when the user has collapsed the details no warning is shown and the submit just doesn't work.
Is there a clean html way to get this working or do I need to use javascript?
I am basically expecting the browser to automatically open the details and show the warning at the checkbox.

See this demo for the problem
https://jsfiddle.net/1jwdm8ov/

```
<html>
    <form>
        <details>
            <input type="checkbox" required="required">
        </details>
        <input type="submit">
    </form>
</html>
```

Comment: There is no way to do this in pure html/css, You'll need javascript

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't think of a way to do this with CSS, but you can use javascript to hook in to the browsers form validation and check if a field is required. If an input is required and has not been completed, you can open the parent details element using `.open = true;`, which will allow the required message to be visible.

```js
var detailInputs = document.querySelectorAll('form details input');

[].forEach.call(detailInputs, function(detailInputs) {
  detailInputs.addEventListener('invalid',function(e){
    detailInputs.parentNode.open = true;
  });
});
```

```html
<form>
  <details>
    <input type="checkbox" required="required">
  </details>
  <input type="submit">
</form>
```

Comment: Thanks, I used jQuery:   ```$('form details input').on('invalid', function () {
    $(this).closest('details').prop('open', true);
  });```

Comment: That works too. The solution above is pure Javascript, so if you are ever concerned about performance in the future, you can use that.